# What should I put as the address and value when creating actions for my DAO in aragonOSx?

Tags: solidity, transactions, uniswap, dao, protocol

In order to use the assets within my DAO, I need to call an `action`. It says that every action requires `{ to, value, data }` parameters.

What should I write as the `address` and `value` if I'm trying to withdraw ETH from my contract? Should I just leave them empty and only specify the data field?

I can see from the `action` struct that I should specify all of them but I was under the impression I could just pass the encoded data as an action..

-- Just to give you some context, I want to swap assets on Uniwap from the DAO's vault and I would just pass an action with encoded data to call the function from the `Uniswap` contracts

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do:

- If you want to simply **transfer ETH**, you would add an action like `{ to: recipientAddr, value: ethAmount, data: null }`
- If you want to **transfer an ERC20**, you would add an action like `{ to: daiContractAddr, value: 0, data: "<encoded-transfer(to, value)>"}`
- If you want to **send an NFT**, it'd be the same as above.
- If you want to **swap Uniswap tokens**, you would encode `{ to: uniswapPoolAddr, value: 0, data: "<encoded-swap(...)>" }`

The `action` struct is `{ to, value, data }`.

You can also use the [aragonOSx SDK](https://github.com/aragon/sdk), which has action encoders to ease this task.
We are also going to have an encoder for token transfers very soon.

You can review the `withdraw` example as well. This will be renamed to `transfer()` in the coming release:
https://github.com/aragon/sdk/blob/develop/modules/client/examples/03-encoders/04-withdraw.ts